# Como relacionar duas classes no mesmo Model Django

Tags: django, model

olá,

sou novo no django e estou tentando buscar informações relacionadas a duas classes diferentes, com 1 variável como "base" para ela.
No caso tenho a classe Cliente e Pedido, e gostaria de incluir um campo onde quando selecionar o Cliente, aparece no meu Model o endereço do mesmo:

---

class Cliente(models.Model):

```
nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=50)
nome_fantasia = models.CharField('Nome Fantasia', max_length=50)
endereco = models.CharField('Endereço', max_length=50)
cidade = models.CharField('Cidade', max_length=50)
estado = models.TextField('Estado', max_length=12, choices=UF_CHOICES)
```

class Pedido(models.Model):

```
SIT_CHOICES = ((tirei pra nao ficar grande))

TIPO_CHOICES = (tirei pra nao ficar grande)

numero = models.CharField('Numero', max_length=9, unique=True)
situacao = models.CharField('Situação', max_length=12, choices=SIT_CHOICES)
data = models.DateField()
fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(Fornecedor, on_delete=models.SET(set_default_fornecedor))
cidade = models.CharField('Cidade', max_length=50)
**cidade_cliente = ??????????????**
cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.SET(set_default_cliente))
preco_produto = models.DecimalField('Preço', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
variedade = models.CharField('Variedade', max_length=12)
tipo = models.CharField('Tipo', max_length=12, choices=TIPO_CHOICES)
quantidade_pedido = models.IntegerField('Quantidade Pedido', help_text="Peso em Tonelada")
```

---

outra dúvida que já me deparei, que terei varias linhas para cada pedido, e preciso incluir também na class Pedido "total do pedido" basicamente seria uma soma de todos os lançamentos de cada pedido, em uma nova classe que irei criar como extrato_pedidos, ou seja, novamente me deparo com a necessidade de buscar informações de outra classe e demonstrar nessa.

---

enfim, to varrendo as respostas do google e ainda nao encontrei resultado.

Answer (score 0):

como existe uma ligação de uma classe para outra que é o ForeignKey

```
                 cls     cls     atributo
```

você pode acessar o pedido.cliente.cidade

e para acessar os pedidos de um cliente

```
for p in cliente.pedido_set.all():
   print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala Gabriel,

consegui trazer a informação para o list_display utilizando o código abaixo, utilizando dentro da classe do admin.py de pedido:

```
def get_cidade(self,obj):
    return obj.fornecedor.cidade
get_cidade.short_description = "Cidade"
```